# adb shell ping, how to get timestamps?

Tags: adb, ping

I am trying to do adb shell ping, with timestamps, but am failing.

```
C:\Program Files\TestTools>adb shell ping
Usage: ping [-LRUbdfnqrvVaA] [-c count] [-i interval] [-w deadline]
        [-p pattern] [-s packetsize] [-t ttl] [-I interface or address]
        [-M mtu discovery hint] [-S sndbuf]
        [ -T timestamp option ] [ -Q tos ] [hop1 ...] destination
```

Trying to use flag -T for it but get "Invalid timestamp type"

Have searched everywhere for available timestamp types and tried different types; like 0, 1, E, U etc but didn't succeed.

Ping without timestamp is OK:

```
C:\Program Files\TestTools>adb shell ping -i 2 -c 100 -s 200 10.11.12.200
PING 10.11.12.200 (10.11.12.200) 200(228) bytes of data.
208 bytes from 10.11.12.200: icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=1824 ms
208 bytes from 10.11.12.200: icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=76.5 ms
208 bytes from 10.11.12.200: icmp_seq=3 ttl=60 time=66.9 ms
^C
```

But the -T flag doesn't work

```
C:\Program Files\TestTools>adb shell ping -i 2 -c 100 -s 200 -T 10.11.12.200
Invalid timestamp type
```

How can I do adb shell ping with timestamping? 
I want a result typically like this:

```
11:39:08.848 : Reply[4] from 10.11.12.200: bytes=200 time=72.7 ms TTL=60
11:39:10.918 : Reply[5] from 10.11.12.200: bytes=200 time=68.8 ms TTL=60
11:39:13.006 : Reply[6] from 10.11.12.200: bytes=200 time=86.9 ms TTL=60
```

Answer (score 1):

`-T` flag works just fine. You are just missing one of the options `tsonly`, `tsandaddr` or `tsprespec` after it. But the output format would be different from what you expect.

Comment: Sorry, what is it that I don't understand...?
It seems that the UE is pinging (I can see that the UE has connected to the RNC, but I don't get any printout in my shell, so I am missing the result...



    C:\Program Files\TestTools>adb shell ping -i 2 -c 100 -s 200 -T tsonly 10.11.12.200

    PING 10.11.12.200 (10.11.12.200) 200(268) bytes of data.